# unlink(/tmp/ci_sessiond8a5986a5bee06644d54af5adc7c8d8851c2f987): Operation not permitted error

Tags: php, codeigniter, unlink

[image]

Sometimes display this `error` in my `updated server`,but if I refresh browser, it browse to normal application.
How can I solve this error.

I'm using `CodeIgniter-3.0.6`

welcome to any help.

Comment: Have you set your sess_save_path something like `$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';` for me I have it in my system folder. Check you have all files and classes like http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0):

its just solved by $config['sess_save_path'] = 'tmp/'; inside the config file, bydefault its NULL there so change to path and make sure that folder have 775 permission.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete file in Codeigniter you can use file helper.

```
$this->load->helper("file");
delete_files($path);
```

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from a lack of permission to remove the file, not from the fact that the PHP standard unlink was called instead of the Code Igniter specific delete_files.

Answer (score -2):

chmod 777 your temp directory. check group/user permissions if your application (server) has the rights for reading writing.

Comment: I did not vote you down but not to good for session folders/files for chmod 777 better something like 0700

Comment: no problem bro. :) an idea can be greater than other!